# Run a while loop for a fixed amount of time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, while-loop

Question might raise some eyebrows since I imagine this is a bit of a misuse of SQL, but I have a function that does a Monte Carlo simulation to optimize some parameters that takes a very long time to run, I would like to be able to have it run over the weekend and then output whatever it has when it's done.

Currently I have it set up like

```
DECLARE INT @iterations = 1000
WHILE @COUNT < @iterations 
BEGIN
   DoStuff()
   @COUNT = @COUNT +1
END
```

Is it possible to design something like this in TSQL?

```
DECLARE INT @maxtime= 72hours
[start counting time]
WHILE @COUNT < @maxtime 
BEGIN
   DoStuff()
END
```

Comment: Aside: [`WaitFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used to sleep for a period of time if you need to limit the resources used by your simulation. You could wait briefly each iteration or a longer wait every _n_ passes.

Comment: In what situations would want to do that?

Comment: If running your simulation causes other queries running on the server to slow to a crawl then you might want to throttle your task back a bit. An easy way is to pause now and then. (I'm assuming that `DoStuff()` completes fairly quickly. If each pass takes 8 hours then `WaitFor` between passes won't help much.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
DECLARE INT @maxtime= 72, DATETIME @endtime;

SET @endtime = DATEADD(HOUR, 72, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WHILE @endtime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
BEGIN
   -- DoStuff()
END;
```

FYI: [`current_timestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the ANSI equivalent of [`getdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).